# Many Senders Sending Multiple Packets to Many Receivers Concurrently

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet

I would like to extend [VeinsInetSampleApplication](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/master/subprojects/veins_inet/src/veins_inet/VeinsInetSampleApplication.cc) to make `node[0]` and `node[1]` send packets to `node[2]` **concurrently**.

I tried to comment the `if-condition` at [L46](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/master/subprojects/veins_inet/src/veins_inet/VeinsInetSampleApplication.cc#L46). However, this did not work.

How to achieve that? I would like to have a scalable solution (e.g., in case I want many senders sending multiple packets to many receivers).

Answer (score 0):

Please find if MAC layer is wired or wireless. If MAC is wireless then concurrent transmissions are possible between adjacent nodes bounded by transmission range. It may result in collision at the receiver if the medum is broadcasting.